# Existence and uniqueness of solutions if Lipschitz constant depends on time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Imagine the following situation:

> Let \begin{cases}x'(t)=f(t,x) \\x(t_0)=x_0\end{cases} be an IVP, where $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R^n}$ is a continuous function, and $\ f$ verifies that $$||f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)||\leq L(t)||x_1 -x_2||,$$ with $\ L(t)$ a continuous function.

Can we prove that there's uniqueness of solution defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$?

I'm thinking on building a nested sequence if compact intervals and then apply Wintner's lemma to prove that we can extent the solution for all $t$. Am I right?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, take the intervals $[x_0-n,x_0+n]$ then there is a unique solution $f_n$ on this interval, and on overlapping intervals they must be the same, hence it is defined for all the reals. I don't know what Wintner's lemma is.

Comment: Broadly, it states that if we have an accumulation point of the graph of a solution on a point, we can extend the solution to that point (with the assumptions I'm taking).

Comment: You don't need that. On any compact interval (of $t$), $f$ is continuous and uniformly Lipschitz with respect to $x$, hence the usual Picard iteration (or more precisely, some power thereof) is a contraction and hence there is a unique solution. Since the solutions must agree on overlapping intervals and the intervals can be taken as large as you want then you are finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L(t)$ is a continuos function, then $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b,$ there's a $k$ such that $L(t) \le k$ $ \forall t \in [a,b]$

Because a continuous function reaches the maximum in a compact

Then f is locally Lipschitz, so by the Picard's Theorem the solution is unique, and use Zorn to define it in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: We could use Wintner's lemma on that last part of your answer (instead of Zorn's) to prove is defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ right?

Comment: And did you mean "globally" Lipschitz?

Comment: It is not true that it is globally Lipschitz,

It is enough that it be locally Lipschitz

Comment: If it's only locally lipschitz I cannot say that there's a unique solution on all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, I can only prove existence but not uniqueness (I can prove uniqueness on a neighbourhood of the initial condition).

Comment: Suppose $x(t)$ is a solution defined in $\mathbb{R}$, then suppose $y(t)$ is another solution defined in $\mathbb{R}$.
Then for each $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b, x(t) = y(t) \forall t \in [a,b]$, because $f$ is Lipschitz there
So $(t) = y(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is a 'Zorn'?